# Diamond question mark in execution of .jar file in linux

Tags: java, linux, character-encoding

I'm getting a diamond with question mark (�) when execute .jar file in Linux.
The characters that displays the diamonds are: ª,º,ñ,ç

My character encode settings in Eclipse IDE are ISO-8859-1, because if I set the encode to UTF-8 in Eclipse I get the diamond question mark also in Eclipse console.

My locale configuration in Linux (openSuse), when I do "locale" command:

```
LANG=es_ES.ISO-8859-1
LC_CTYPE="ISO-8859-1"
LC_NUMERIC="ISO-8859-1"
LC_TIME="ISO-8859-1"
LC_COLLATE="ISO-8859-1"
LC_MONETARY="ISO-8859-1"
LC_MESSAGES="ISO-8859-1"
LC_PAPER="ISO-8859-1"
LC_NAME="ISO-8859-1"
LC_ADDRESS="ISO-8859-1"
LC_TELEPHONE="ISO-8859-1"
LC_MEASUREMENT="ISO-8859-1"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="ISO-8859-1"
LC_ALL=ISO-8859-1
```

I read and check more references of this problem, but I don't know how to solve this, can anyone help me?

Comment: That's the unicode replacement character. It means you're trying to print a `ISO-8859-1` character/byte in an `UTF-8` environment, and the byte doesn't map to an `UTF-8` byte sequence. If you're getting it as a terminal output, then the terminal may be in `UTF-8` and not `ISO-8859-1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to print a `ISO-8859-1` character/byte in an `UTF-8` environment, and the byte doesn't map to an `UTF-8` byte sequence. If you're getting it as a terminal output (the terminal is in UTF-8 encoding), then you should change that character/byte in ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 for example: ñ in UTF 8 is Ã±. Source for UTF-8 characters [here](http://www.merinomartinez.com/2012/06/tabla-de-conversion-de-simbolos-utf-8-a-iso-8859-1-ansi/).
Look at [this](https://www.quora.com/Why-do-we-use-UTF-8) post which explains why to use UTF-8 instead of other encoding types.